# Open a downloaded file with a third party application

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an application that allows users to download files from the server, these files can be pretty much anything.

I am at the point where a user is able to download a file to their phone but I can not figure out how to allow the user to open the files from the app, for example say a user has download a word file (.docx), when they select the file in my application I want the file to either open in the default .docx viewer or present the user with applications that can open the file. (Similar to how WhatsApp handles it)

I have tried using Linking.openURL('file:///pathtofile/filename.docx') but I get an error saying Could not open URL file:///pathtofile/filename.docx, exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

I'm currently using Expo and would much prefer not to have to detach my app.

---

Update:

I ended up detaching from Expo and built native modules to handle this.